# How to run Java Program with class having sub class in different package hierarchy?

Tags: java

I have two classes like:

```
Class GetData is like:

package com
public class GetData{
private String name = "John";
public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
}

package com.test;
import com.GetData;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       GetData data = new GetData();
       System.out.println("Welcome "+data.getName());
   }
}
```

When I'm trying compile the Test class it throws an error like `undefined symbol` for `GetData`. I tried like:

```
javac -cp .com/GetData.class Test.java
```

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with how you're specifying the classpath. You just need to specify the directory which is at the root of the directory containing the classes, so if you've got `com/GetData.class` you just need:

```
javac -cp . Test.java
```

Although you should really have the source code in a directory hierarchy matching the packages, so I'd expect

```
javac -cp . com/test/Test.java
```

Then run with:

```
javac -cp . com.test.Test
```

All of this is assuming that `.` *isn't* on your classpath - it is by default, so you may well find you can just use:

```
javac com/test/Test.java
java com.test.Test
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but it;s not working for me. It's throw an error like `File not found : com\test\Test.java` . kindly suggest me some other approaches

Comment: @Samraan: Well presumably that's because the file isn't where I've suggested it should be. So either put it there, or specify where the file actually *is*.

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem how you are running the code. Simply you can run with eclipse Run As->Java Application if you are not sure how to run through command console.

Comment: I know how to run it through eclipse...but my requirement is to run through command line only which I have already mentioned....